# flash opening new page rather than in the same browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, flash

Hey another member of my team made some flash but when I embed it in asp.net

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <object width="425" height="344">
      <embed src="css/index.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="344"></embed>
     </object>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

It opens a new page rather than in the same browser. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean it opens a new window? Does the swf file open by it self in another window without any html? Or is there a link in the swf file that needs to open in the same window? If so, its your flash buddy that needs to fix it.

AS3:
navigateToURL(new URLRequest(url), "_same");

but _same should be standard just as in html a href target.

Comment: @Kodiak Hahaha it might be. I've never used it, as its the standard. No point then :)